# VS Code @ts-check in JavaScript file not checking all things - nonexistent property not erroring

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, ts-check

[image]

```js
// @ts-check

const obj = {
  str: `a string`,
};

console.log(obj.nonexistant); // no error (it should be erroring)

let num = 0; // type number
num = obj.str; // has error (good)
```

Why is the first issue not showing the red underline error/problem in VS Code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typing is fine. I'm pretty sure this is a configuration thing. Try adding a [jsconfig.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig) with [`"strict": true,`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strict) or [`"noImplicitAny": true,`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noImplicitAny) in its `compilerOptions` field, or a [tsconfig.json](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig) with the same, along with [`"allowJs": true,`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#allowJs) and [`"checkJs": true,`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#checkJs).

Comment: Either `strict` or `noImplicitAny` both work